# wp_update_post does not update post_name

Tags: wp-update-post

I have a post with `id=1, post_title = 'Some post title'` and `slug(post_name)='some-post-title`.

I want to update its title and slug.

```
$update_args = array(
    'ID' => '1',
    'post_title' => 'Test purpose',
    'post_name' => 'new-slug'
);
$result = wp_update_post($update_args);
```

After that post title is updated but slug stays the same(some-post-title) but not new-slug.

I cannot understand how can i update post-slug.

Comment: Did you check this? - http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/46086/regenerate-slugs-from-title-of-posts

Comment: @HelpingHands 
Code is the same. As you can see here http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/46114/43932 wp_update_post uses same keys but wrapped in some conditions.

Comment: Maruti Mohanty describe here how to change post & page slug :
https://drujoopress.wordpress.com/2013/05/17/update-postpage-slug-on-the-fly/

Comment: Resolved. I checked wp_update_post function https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.2.2/src/wp-includes/post.php#L3570 and found this function returns wp_insert_post function https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.2.2/src/wp-includes/post.php#L3614. After that i changed from $result = wp_update_post($update_args); to $result = wp_insert_post($update_args); Also in the code above 'ID' => '1', should be 'ID' => 1, . Now post_name slug is updated.

Comment: Update information: WPML cause the problem of post_name does not update. More info here https://wpml.org/forums/topic/permalink-for-pages-are-not-created-when-wpml-is-active-save_post-action/