# Automatically add date to the auto generation of post slug

Tags: posts, customization, slug, date-time

I need to customize the slug when you add new post and after you write title it creates automatically slug. I want to add before the auto title of the post the current date on this format `d-m-y` so the final slug will be `d-m-y-posttitle`.

Tried this just to add random numbers but didn't work:

```
function append_slug($data) {
global $post_ID;

if (!empty($data['post_name']) && $data['post_status'] == "publish" && $data['post_type'] == "post") {

        if( !is_numeric(substr($data['post_name'], -4)) ) {
            $random = rand(1111,9999);
            $data['post_name'] = sanitize_title($data['post_title'], $post_ID);
            $data['post_name'] .= '-' . $random;
        }

}
 return $data; } add_filter('wp_insert_post_data', 'append_slug', 10);
```

Comment: What about `%day%-%monthnum%-%year%-%postname%` in your permalinks?

Comment: @birgire would be good solution if I did that when I start my site but I have 1500 posts that already edited manually with the date slug so if put `%day%-%monthnum%-%year%-%postname%` in permalinks will duplicate the date `d-m-y-d-m-y-posttitle`

Comment: ok, I see, it just feels unflexible what you're trying to do. Let's say you wanted to swap the order later on, from `d-m-y-posttitle` to `y-m-d-posttitle`, or just `posttitle`, but that would give the same problem. One way around it would be to modify the old ones in bulk with some programming, I'm sure there are examples on this sites for that (just remember to backup before!)

Comment: @birgire would be good idea if use mysql query and remove the date from old posts?

Comment: I think that should be possible, if your date part has a fixed length. But there are no regexp-replaces in MySQL afaik, but it does in MariaDB.

Comment: [This thread](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/46086/regenerate-slugs-from-title-of-posts) has some worthwhile ideas on how you might cycle through all posts using `wp_insert_post` (the `wp_update_post` does not update the `post_name` column in DB, as described in this [this thread](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/175382/wp-update-post-does-not-update-post-name)) and then make use `sanitize_title` to reslug all posts using the title.