# How to generate slugs?

Tags: slug, wp-update-post

I have the following situation. I accidentally updated `post_name` column in `wp_posts` tables for all rows. Now I need to update those back somehow. I have researched that `WP` uses this function to generate slugs `wp_unique_post_slug`.

Can anyone please provide me with steps how to do this? I have no idea of `PHP`, plugins etc. What will I need to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @toscho already answered [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/46114/15680), yes this is possible.

You just need to copy this code into the `functions.php` of your theme, and there you go.

```
// get all posts
$posts = get_posts( array (  'numberposts' => -1 ) );

foreach ( $posts as $post )
{
    // check the slug and run an update if necessary 
    $new_slug = sanitize_title( $post->post_title );

    // use this line if you have multiple posts with the same title
    $new_slug = wp_unique_post_slug( $new_slug, $post->ID, $post->post_status, $post->post_type, $post->post_parent );

    if ( $post->post_name != $new_slug )
    {
        wp_update_post(
            array (
                'ID'        => $post->ID,
                'post_name' => $new_slug
            )
        );
    }
}
```

You can also create a plugin for that, if you create a `yourplugin.php` file in your plugins folder, with a valid plugin header and the above code:

```
<?php
    /*
    Plugin Name: Your Plugin
    Plugin URI: http://www.example.com
    Description: description
    Version: 0.1
    Author: thatsyou
    Author URI: http://www.yourdomain.com
    License: MIT
    */

    //yourcode
?>
```

Please be aware that if you copy this code into your `functions.php` or your activate the plugin, it is executed all the time. You can get some ideas on how to execute code only once here: [Best Practices](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/131697/what-is-your-best-practice-to-execute-one-time-scripts)

Comment: Hello! Thank you for the answer. Does `wp_update_post` internally call `wp_unique_post_slug`?

Comment: actually no. see updated answer.

Comment: Can we filter temporarily here `$posts = get_posts( array (  'numberposts' => -1 ) );` by specific `ID` so I can check it for one post first?

Comment: if you set numberposts to 1, not to -1, you only change one post. -1 means no limit.

Comment: No, no. I mean to filter it by post_id, not the first one.

Comment: you could do a get_post( $id ) to retrieve only one, that would be more efficient.

Comment: Ok, thank you for all your help. I will try this and will mark if it works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36015/discussion-between-giorgi-nakeuri-and-fischi).