# Updating posts exceeds maximum execution time

Tags: errors, wp-update-post

Prehistory from [How to generate slugs?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/218343/how-to-generate-slugs/):

> I have the following situation. I accidentally updated `post_name`
>   column in `wp_posts` tables for all rows. Now I need to update those
>   back somehow.

I have implemented the following solution:

```
<?php
    /*
    Plugin Name: Your Plugin
    Plugin URI: http://www.example.com
    Description: description
    Version: 0.1
    Author: thatsyou
    Author URI: http://www.yourdomain.com
    License: MIT
    */

$update_count = 0;

for ($x = 0; $x <= 7823; $x++)
{
    $post = get_post($x);

    if (!empty($post))
    {
        // check the slug and run an update if necessary 
        $new_slug = sanitize_title( $post->post_title );

        // use this line if you have multiple posts with the same title
        $new_slug = wp_unique_post_slug( $new_slug, $post->ID, $post->post_status, $post->post_type, $post->post_parent );

        if ( $post->post_name != $new_slug )
        {
            wp_update_post(
                array (
                    'ID'        => $post->ID,
                    'post_name' => $new_slug
                )
            );

            $update_count+=1;
        }
    }
}

echo $update_count;
?>
```

I am iterating through all needed `ID`s, selecting post and updating it's slug. When I activated the plugin it seemed to work and I think it then stuck somewhere in the middle. What can be the reason for this?

Also I have noticed that it doesn't produce slug for revisions like `9-revision-v1`. It just does `title` sanitizing for revisions. I don't know, may be there are some more inconsistencies for other post types. I am just not good in this domain.

Also I see that 3 rows where updated with plugin(`post_modified` is the same when I activated the plugin), but `post_name`s are the same for those. I was expecting `wp_unique_post_slug` would generate distinct post names.

Comment: Do you actually have 7823 posts. If so, you are exceeding maximum execution time, that is why your process "gets stuck". Also, why do you need to update revisions

Comment: @PieterGoosen, yes there are ~7000 posts with some gaps in IDs. Because slug was `9-revision-v1` before my mistake. Then I have updated it with `bla-bla`(title was `Bla Bla`). So when I run my plugin it generates `bla-bla`, but I was wondering if somehow `9-revision-v1` can be generated? And what can I to do to workaround time out?

Comment: Sorry to say, but the solution you are using is not going to cut the deal, it is extremely expensive which will cause a lot of issues. I will try to come up with something better

Comment: since this is a fix and not something you'd need to run all the time, why not just set the limit manually for each 1000 or so and run it 8 times...

Comment: @majick, I just don't know where I can set this? Cal you tell?

Comment: I will update my post later for post revisions, I need to leave now. My answer will take care of the time-out issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do have a large amount of posts which **will** crash your server (*due to maximum execution time being exceeded*) with such an expensive operation. We will need to run this in a much more cleverer way.

First of all, we would want to get all posts, except `revision` and `nav_menu_item`. Revision `post_name`s are build in a different way, and trying to handle them with other post types will indeed also crash your server

Secondly, we need to run a filter on `WP_Query` in order that we only get the ID, post_name, post_title, post_status, post_type and post_parent fields of the post. This will greatly ease the strain on your server

Thirdly, we need to ignore updating all term and post meta caches. This also adds extra unnecessary strain on your resources, so we need to exclude updating them because, frankly, we do not need post terms and meta

### ALL POST TYPES EXCEPT REVISIONS

With such a large amount of posts, you would probably need to run it a few times, but with a huge improvement from the code you are using, you might probably get away with running it once

You can try the following: (*You can drop this into `functions.php` or replace your existing code in the plugin with my code*)

```
add_action( 'wp', function ()
{
    global $wpdb;

    add_filter( 'posts_fields', function ( $fields, \WP_Query $q ) use ( $wpdb )
    {
        remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ );

        // Only target a query where the new custom_query parameter is set with a value of custom_meta_1
        if ( 'custom_meta_1' === $q->get( 'custom_query' ) ) {
            // Only get the ID, post_name, post_title, post_status, post_type and post_parent fields to reduce server load
            $fields = "
                $wpdb->posts.ID,
                $wpdb->posts.post_title,
                $wpdb->posts.post_name,
                $wpdb->posts.post_type,
                $wpdb->posts.post_status,
                $wpdb->posts.post_parent
            ";
        }

        return $fields;
    }, 10, 2);

    // Get all public post types
    $post_types = get_post_types( ['public' => true] );

    $args = [
        'post_type'              => $post_types,
        'posts_per_page'         => -1,              
        'suppress_filters'       => false,           // Allow the posts_fields filter
        'custom_query'           => 'custom_meta_1', // New parameter to allow that our filter only target this query
        'update_post_term_cache' => false,
        'update_post_meta_cache' => false
    ];
    $q = get_posts( $args );

    // Make sure we have posts before we continue, if not, bail
    if ( $q ) {

        // Loop through the posts
        foreach ( $q as $single_post ) {
            // Sanitize our post title
            $new_slug = sanitize_title( $single_post->post_title );

            // Check if our $new_slug is not equal to our post_name
            if ( $single_post->post_name === $new_slug )
                continue; // Do nothing further

            // Our new slug and post name does not match, lets save a unique post_name
            $post_name = wp_unique_post_slug( 
                $new_slug, 
                $single_post->ID,
                $single_post->post_status, 
                $single_post->post_type, 
                $single_post->post_parent       
            );

            // Last change to bail before we update the post_name field
            if ( false !== stripos( $single_post->post_name, $post_name ) )
                continue;

            //Update the post_name field, wpdb::update is the quickest
            $wpdb->update(   
                'wp_posts', 
                ['post_name' => $post_name],    // string
                ['ID'        => $single_post->ID], 
                '%s',
                '%s' 
            );  
        } // endforeach $q
    }
}, PHP_INT_MAX );
```

### EDIT - REVISIONS

The code above, as stated, should be used for all posts except revisions as revision's `post_name` is build differently.

The code below will update the `post_name` field for revisions. You should not run this code together with the code above, it will definitely break your servers' back with the amount of posts you have. You should run code block one, remove it and then run code block two, and remove it once done, specially code block two as it is really expensive.

Here is the code:

```
add_action( 'wp', function ()
{
    global $wpdb;

    add_filter( 'posts_fields', function ( $fields, \WP_Query $q ) use ( $wpdb )
    {
        remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ );

        // Only target a query where the new custom_query parameter is set with a value of custom_meta_1
        if ( 'custom_meta_1' === $q->get( 'custom_query' ) ) {
            // Only get the ID, post_name, post_title, post_status, post_type and post_parent fields to reduce server load
            $fields = "
                $wpdb->posts.ID,
                $wpdb->posts.post_title,
                $wpdb->posts.post_name,
                $wpdb->posts.post_type,
                $wpdb->posts.post_status,
                $wpdb->posts.post_parent
            ";
        }

        return $fields;
    }, 10, 2);

    $args = [
        'post_type'              => 'any',
        'post_status'            => 'any',
        'posts_per_page'         => -1,
        'custom_query'           => 'custom_meta_1', // New parameter to allow that our filter only target this query
        'update_post_term_cache' => false,
        'update_post_meta_cache' => false
    ];
    $q = get_posts( $args );

    // Make sure we have posts before we continue, if not, bail
    if ( $q ) {
        // Now we can get the post revions and loop throught them
        foreach ( $q as $single_post ) {
            $rev_args = [
                'post_type'              => 'revision',
                'post_status'            => 'inherit',
                'post_parent'            => $single_post->ID,
                'posts_per_page'         => -1,
                'order'                  => 'ASC',
                'custom_query'           => 'custom_meta_1', // New parameter to allow that our filter only target this query
                'update_post_term_cache' => false,
                'update_post_meta_cache' => false
            ];
            $revisions = get_posts( $rev_args );

            // Make sure we have revions before we continue
            if ( $revisions ) {
                // Loop through the revisions and set post_name
                foreach ( $revisions as $key=>$revisions ) {
                    // Build a revision post slug in the format {$post->post_parent}-revision-v{$key + 1}
                    $post_name = $single_post->ID . '-revision-v' . ( $key + 1 );

                    // Make sure that we don't have a post_name yet with the name $post_name
                    if ( $revisions->post_name === $post_name )
                        continue; // Do nothing

                    //Update the post_name field, wpdb::update is the quickest
                    $wpdb->update(   
                        'wp_posts', 
                        ['post_name' => $post_name],    // string
                        ['ID'        => $revisions->ID], 
                        '%s',
                        '%s' 
                    );  
                }
            }
        }
    }
}, PHP_INT_MAX );
```

### EDIT - Between 2015-07-08 23:23:45 and 2016-02-21 09:42:31

If you only need to target posts and revisions between the two specific dates, you can add the following inside your query args in `$args` in both blocks of code with a `date_query`

```
'date_query' => [
    [
        'after'     => '2015-07-08 23:23:45',
        'before'    => '2016-02-21 09:42:31',
    ],
],
```

So

```
$args = [
    'post_type'              => $post_types,
    'posts_per_page'         => -1,              
    'suppress_filters'       => false,           // Allow the posts_fields filter
    'custom_query'           => 'custom_meta_1', // New parameter to allow that our filter only target this query
    'update_post_term_cache' => false,
    'update_post_meta_cache' => false
];
```

in block one becomes

```
$args = [
    'post_type'              => $post_types,
    'posts_per_page'         => -1,              
    'suppress_filters'       => false,           // Allow the posts_fields filter
    'custom_query'           => 'custom_meta_1', // New parameter to allow that our filter only target this query
    'update_post_term_cache' => false,
    'update_post_meta_cache' => false,
    'date_query'             => [
        [
            'after'          => '2015-07-08 23:23:45',
            'before'         => '2016-02-21 09:42:31',
        ],
    ],
];
```

Comment: Ok, I will wait for your edit, because I have no idea of all this.

Comment: I have edited the code, must just write another section for revisions. The code in my answer in the mean time should change all  post slugs to your needs, except for revisions ;-)

Comment: Great! If I just replace this code in my plugin, it will execute when I activate it, right? Also can I filter posts like `post_id < 300` in order to not touch new posts?

Comment: I have updated my answer, there are two code blocks now. Don't run them together, code block two is quite expensive and will break your site halfway through the operation. First run block code one, then remove it once done, then run block code 2 until you're done, then remove it. New posts should not be altered, but I can add another piece of code to only get posts before a certain date

Comment: Let me know if I should add the section to only get posts before a certain date

Comment: Pieter, thank you for all your help. `post_date > 2015-07-08 23:23:45 and < 2016-02-21 09:42:31` or `ID > 4834 and < 7824`. Whichever is more comfortable. I think I have a backup till `4834` so I will manually update it.

Comment: See my update, it should be what you need. ;-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36033/discussion-between-giorgi-nakeuri-and-pieter-goosen).

Comment: `add_filter( 'posts_fields', function ( $fields, \WP_Query $q ) use ( $wpdb ) 
{`.
`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')' in /home/a2ztradies/public_html/wp-content/plugins/aaa/testCopy1.php on line 38`
Can you look at this please?

Comment: I think it is `$post_types = get_post_types( ['public' => true] );` that throws exception.